# The blob supplied is not valid when deploying data factory pipeline with custom .net activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've been getting this "useful" error message when deploying an experimental data factory pipeline that has a DotNetActivity within it.

> Entity provisioning failed: The blob supplied is not valid. Blob:
>   customactivity/package.zip. Error code: . Error message: .

I've been reading trouble shooting tips and double checking connection strings, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

After double checking everything in particular blob storage connection strings, I was eventually able to resolve it by copying the connection string from the azure portal -> storage account -> access keys into the azure storage linked service settings.

I can only theorize that there is a subtlety in the connection string format which results in a poor error message from the pipeline provisioning.

Interestingly, I can now put a completely wrong access key into the storage account linked service, redeploy it along with the the pipeline and it doesn't complain about provisioning. So perhaps there is additional checks done on the first provision.